# How to set the TLS frame buffer size when using node https server

Tags: node.js

I am relatively new to node. I am using the https.Server class but need to reduce the TLS frame buffer size as my client has limited memory.

```
var https = require('https');
var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) { ... }
```

From what I have read

```
tls.SLAB_BUFFER_SIZE=N
```

to set the buffer size but how do you do this when using the https.Server class.

I have tried

```
https.SLAB_BUFFER_SIZE=N
```

but this doesnt work. https.Server is described as a subclass of tls.Server but javascript classes are a bit of a mystery to me!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var https = require('https');
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

tls.SLAB_BUFFER_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

at least it runs

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this does not seem to affect the frame size for the https server. This will only modify the frame size for the tls server. At the moment I am using a tls server and manually parsing the http which is not ideal and prone to error. I think I need to understand better how https is a subcalss of tls.